# Legendary prefix chance in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

Does anyone know if there is an equal chance of getting any type of legendary or is there a set chance for each prefix? (Prefix as in Wounding, Powerful, etc)

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know if we know the answer, but here's something somewhat relevant from Nukapedia's [Legendary Weapon Effects page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects):

Comment: It appears (though this cannot currently be outright confirmed) that while the legendary weapons and armor that are found on enemies are random, there are certain "pools" of said weapon and armor types specifically tied to the type of enemy and location in which they are spawned. Certain legendary variants of weapons encountered early in the game - such as laser muskets and pipe pistols - will not spawn on Gunners, but will always have a chance to be found on legendary enemies with an area-specific low level cap (e.g. the ghouls in Super Duper Mart).

Answer (score 2):

According to NukaPedia there is no set chance of a certain type of legendary weapon dropping. Legendary weapons are only able to be found on the bodies of "Legendary" variants of enemies and the type of enemy doesn't effect what weapon you'll get. e.g. A Legendary Glowing Radroach could drop a Furious Pipe Rifle, or a Never Ending Assault Rifle.

After all, I'm only paraphrasing the wiki, more info can be found on [NukaPedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects).